# Comparing two objects by multiple properties

Tags: javascript

How do I do the following in a more readable manner?:

```
if (nextProps.a !== this.props.a ||
      nextProps.b !== this.props.b ||
      nextProps.cc !== this.props.cc ||
      nextProps.d !== this.props.d){

}
```

Note that the object in question has more properties that the just a, b, cc, and d but I want to the comparison for only these properties. I'm using ES6.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
isOk = true;
props = ["a","b","cc","d"]; //replace this with whatever your properties are from
for(i in props){
     if(nextProps[i]==this.props[i]){
         isOk = false;
          break;
     }
}

if(isOk){
   // :)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(nextProps);

var result = false;
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    result = nextProps[names[i]] !== this.props[name[i]];
    if (result)
        break;
}
if (result) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a method:

```js
// Comparison of all properties equal
function propsEqual(obj1, obj2, props) {
  var equal = true;
  var propsLen = props.len;
  while(propsLen-- && equal) {
    var prop = props[propLen];
    equal = obj1[prop] === obj2[prop];
  }
  return equal;
}

// Comparison of any properties equal
function anyPropsEqual(obj1, obj2, props) {
  var equal = false;
  var propsLen = props.len;
  while(propsLen-- && !equal) {
    var prop = props[propLen];
    equal = obj1[prop] === obj2[prop];
  }
  return equal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the List.some:

```
["orgId","roleId","userGroupId","userId"].some( v => a[v] !== b[v])
```

```js
let a = {orgId: 1,roleId:2, userGroupId:3, userId:4};
let b = {orgId: 1,roleId:2, userGroupId:3, userId:4};
console.log(["orgId","roleId","userGroupId","userId"].some( v => a[v] !== b[v]));

a = {orgId: 1,roleId:2, userGroupId:3, userId:5};
b = {orgId: 1,roleId:2, userGroupId:3, userId:4};
console.log(["orgId","roleId","userGroupId","userId"].some( v => a[v] !== b[v]));

a = {orgId: 1,roleId:2, userGroupId:3, userId:4};
b = {orgId: 2,roleId:2, userGroupId:3, userId:4};
console.log(["orgId","roleId","userGroupId","userId"].some( v => a[v] !== b[v]));
```